# has_many, belongs_to relation in active record migration rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have a `User` model and a `Task` model. I have not mentioned any relation between them while creating them.

I need to establish that `User` `has_many` `Tasks` and a `Task` `belongs_to` `User` through a migration

What would be the migration generation command for establishing that relationship?

Comment: I Hope this link will help you to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354724/how-to-create-an-association-between-two-rails-models

Comment: Could you mark @Alter_Lagos answer as the correct one to help others?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You could call:

```
rails g model task user:references
```

which will generates an `user_id` column in the `tasks` table and will modify the `task.rb` model to add a `belongs_to :user` relatonship. Please note, you must to put manually the `has_many :tasks` or  `has_one :task` relationship to the `user.rb` model.

If you already have the model generated, you could create a migration with the following:

```
rails g migration AddUserToTask user:belongs_to
```

which will generate:

```
class AddUserToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :tasks, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

the only difference with this approach is, the `belongs_to :user` relationship in the `task.rb` model won't be created automatically, so you must create it for your own.

Comment: It'd be good to note that :belongs_to is an alias of :references, I think.  Good answer though. :)

Answer (score 31):

To answer the question, "What would be the migration generation command for establishing that relation?"( Meaning, how do you add a migration for existing models with a relationship like `User has_many Tasks` & `Task belongs_to User`)

The the easiest way for me to remember is like this:

```
>rails g migration AddUserToTask user:belongs_to
```

or

```
>rails g migration AddUserToTask user:references
```

`:belongs_to` is just an alias of `:references`, so either will do the same thing.

Doing it this way, the command will infer the name of the table from the migration name, set up a change method that will add the column for relationship, and configure it to be indexed:

```
class AddUserToTask < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :tasks, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

After generating that you:

```
>rake db:migrate
```

Finally, you still have to add the usual relations to your models, as is stated in the other answers, but I think this is the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 21):

**This is how the migration should be created normally:**

`rails g scaffold child parent:references`

---

**I forgot to add `parent:references` when I created the table, what should I do?**

*Option 1: Destroy the table and start over*

If you don't  have a lot defined in the model/db about the child table.  Your best bet might just be to run `rails destroy scaffold child`, and then run 
`rails g scaffold child parent:references` over it.  Be sure to add the line `drop_table :children if table_exists? :children` before create table in the file that creates the new table.  (That way if anyone pulls your code they can just run the migrations and be done.) However, it seems more probable that you will have data you don't want to lose in the child model already. 
In that case:

*Option 2: Write a migration to add the references*

`rails g migration add_parent_refs_to_child`

```
## XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_add_parent_refs_to_child.rb
class AddParentRefsToChild < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :child, :parent, index: true
  end
end
```

See [add_reference](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference)

Additionally, don't forget to make sure the parent model `has_[one | many] :children`, and that the child model `belongs_to :parent`.

---

**How not to do it:**

You may be tempted to add the `parent_id` manually.  Don't.  Conventionally this sort of operation is handled through a migration, or within the initial table creation.  Manual addition will detract from the maintainability of the project.

The [Ruby on Rails guide to association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) has more information on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

The Relationship in Rails is taken care by model not by Rails.

So you just need to define this relationship in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And just make sure that a `user_id` field is present in the migration for creating the "tasks" table.

Comment: yes jha.. i could add that, just wanted to know the migration command in terminal.

Comment: in that case just run
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_task. it will generate migration file from you and here you can add and remove the columns

Comment: `rails g migration AddUserIdToTask user_id:integer`

Answer (score 4):

There is no special migration command that would be used.

In your User model you will put

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the corresponding migration file for the tasks you have the following field added     user_id

Take a look at this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: This is well and good, however, if the table users does not include the `t.references :user` in the task table creation, then this ^ will have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

The migration will add the user's id to the task table so they know about each other

```
rails g migration AddUserIdToTask user_id:integer
```

then

```
rake db:migrate
```

And after update your controllers and views so that tasks can't be created on their own but must correspond to a user

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, you should instead make sure that when you define the table you say `t.references :user`.  Or, if the table has already been created without it, write a migration to do so for you.