# has_many association migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I m working on a Rails project (Rails version 4.2.3). 
I created a `User` and `Task` model but did not include any association between them during creation. 
Now i want one `user`  to have many `tasks` and one `task` belonging to one `user`.

Through `rails g migration AddUserToTask user:belongs_to` from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894688/has-many-belongs-to-relation-in-active-record-migration-rails-4)
i was able to insert the foreign user_id key in the tasks table. But how to i add a the `has_many` migration? I updated the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
end
```

but i m not sure how i have to write the migration. So far i wrote this:

```
class addTasksToUser < ActiveRecords::Migration
  def change
    update_table :users do |t|
      t.has_many :tasks
    end 
    add_index :users, taks_id
  end
end
```

But `rake db:migrate` is not performing any action. Is this the correct way to setup the `has_many` relationship?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Add associations in model and corresponding fields in migration.

Comment: Just add associations in model.

Comment: for me, the better answer for this question, was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17928074/4179050

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set up associations in models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Delete the migration file you've shown.

Add references to `tasks` table (assuming you already have `tasks` table):

```
rails g migration add_references_to_tasks user:references
```

Migrate the database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

---

If you don't have `tasks` table yet, create one:

```
rails g migration create_tasks name due_date:datetime user:references # add any columns here
```

Migrate the database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

---

From now on your tasks will have `user_id` attribute.

Comment: Hi Andray thanks for you detailed answer. My tasks already have a user_id. How do i get the other way so, that my user have many tasks. I highly struggle implementing this direction

Comment: @theDrifter if your `tasks` table already has `user_id` column, than as I've said, you only need to ensure associations on models levels(the very first part of my answer).

Comment: Hey @Andrey thanks for your sicking with me :). I did setup the models accordingly. How do i get the user associated with a set of tasks and also translate it to my table structure?

Comment: OK i got my mistake. I did not fully understand the many_to_one relationship. Now i want the tasks which belong to one user. I just call the tasks for a specific user_id. I thought i have to store each task_id in the user table which makes absolutely no sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `has_many :tasks` to the `User` model and `belongs_to :user` to the `Task` model. In your migration file, delete all the current body of the `change` method and include a `add_index :tasks, :user_id` line. After that, run the migration normally.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but efforts are only to improve on this.
I think what you were going for was to show **reference foreign key in the table**.
In which case:

```
class addTasksToUser < ActiveRecords::Migration   
   def change
     update_table :users do |t|
     t.references :task
   end   
end
```

Please make sure your references to the table with the primary key is singular.