# Rails generate has_many migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post

I have two models, Collection and Book. A book belongs to a Collection and a Collection has many Books.

I have generated my models this way:

```
bin/rails generate model Collection title:string plot:text
bin/rails generate model Book title:string plot:text Collection:references
```

Then it generates these models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Collection
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

So I have read in other answers like this one [has_many, belongs_to relation in active record migration rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894688/has-many-belongs-to-relation-in-active-record-migration-rails-4) I have to manually add the has_many field in the Collection model.

Ok then it looks like this:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

And then I run the migration:

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

Then I add some data, a couple of books and a collection with (**I am not sure if the collection post is correct**):

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"title" : "Book 1", "plot" : "book"}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/books
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"title" : "Book 2", "plot" : "book"}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/books
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"title" : "Collection", "plot" : "collection", "book_id" : [1,2]}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/collections
```

Then I check them in http://127.0.0.1:3000/collections and it crashes

```
  def index
    @collections = Collection.all
    render :json => @collections.as_json(
                  :include => :book
                )
  end
```

It says

> undefined method `book' for # Did you
>   mean? books books=

If I try that and replace book with books then the books list is empty:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Collection","plot":"collection","created_at":"2016-04-11T17:53:38.892Z","updated_at":"2016-04-11T17:53:38.892Z","books":[]}]
```

This is my create method:

```
  def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)

    @collection.save
    redirect_to @collection
  end

  private
    def collection_params
      params.permit(:title, :plot, :book_id)
    end
```

Shouldnt it store the book inside collection? Why is not appearing in the index view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want collection_id to live on the books table if books belong to collections then when creating the data you would want to do it as:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{
  "title" : "Collection", 
  "plot" : "collection"}' 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/collections

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{
  "title" : "Book 1", 
  "plot" : "book", 
  "collection_id": "1"}' 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/books

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -d '{
  "title" : "Book 2", 
  "plot" : "book", 
  "collection_id": "1"}' 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/books
```

Comment: Ofc, that makes sense! I knew I was mixing up badly with the POST, thanks!