# adding relation through migrations in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the advice of this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894688/has-many-belongs-to-relation-in-active-record-migration-rails-4). An entree belongs_to a venue. So I expect a foreign key named venue_id on the entrees table. I generated the following:

```
rails g migration AddEntreeToVenue entree:belongs_to
```

It created the following migration:

```
class AddEntreeToVenue < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :venues, :entree, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

But after running db:migrate, I look at the entrees table and no foreign key:

```
Indexes:
    "entrees_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "venues" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_0cf11999c6" FOREIGN KEY (entree_id) REFERENCES entrees(id)
```

What it appeared to do was add the foreign key to the venues table, not the entrees table. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should have added the reference to the entrees table.  Do:  add_reference :entrees, :venue, index: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generator command specified that Rails should create a `belongs_to` column on Venues. What you actually want is the opposite:

```
rails g migration AddVenueToEntrees venue:belongs_to
```

This will create a migration that modifies `entrees`, adding a `venue_id` column with a foreign key constraint on `venues.id`.