# association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

This is the error I get when I try to fill in the book's form: `undefined method 'books' for nil:NilClass` & it highlights this line: `@book = @owner.books.build(params[:book])`

This is what I've done so far:

What am I missing?

Two models: owner and book

**Here's the schema**

```
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "isbn"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "owner_id"
end

add_index "books", ["owner_id"], name: "index_books_on_owner_id"

create_table "owners", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end
end
```

Here are the models:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :books
 end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :owner  
  validates :owner_id, presence: true
 end
```

This is in book controller:

```
  def create
   @book = @owner.books.build(params[:book])
     respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @book }
    else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end
```

**EDIT**

This is in the owner's controller:

```
   def create
      @owner = Owner.new(owner_params)

     respond_to do |format|
     if @owner.save
       format.html { redirect_to @owner, notice: 'Owner was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @owner }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @owner.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
end
end
```

**EDIT 2**

```
   private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_owner
       @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
     end

   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def owner_params
      params.require(:owner).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :title, :isbn)
     end
```

**EDIT 3 **

The method I used in book's controller in create came from this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354724/how-to-create-an-association-between-two-rails-models)

Comment: Your `@owner` object is nil. How do you set the `@owner` object?

Comment: @Masud, what do you mean? Sorry, still figuring my way around ROR stuff.

Comment: Is there any `before_action` set_owner method for `create` action?

Comment: @Masud, no. Will add owner's create method in post

Comment: No. Before create @book, you need to get @owner object. Like `@owner=Owner.find(params[:id])`

Comment: @Masud, just added that in my post. it's in the `set_owner` method which was automatically created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68788/discussion-between-masud-and-user27307254534534534543).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says that @owner is nil. At `BooksController` you need to get the @owner object. As Owner and Books has nested association. So you need to define the routes like:

```
resources :owners do
   resources :books
end
```

At `BooksController`

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController do 

   def create
     @owner=Owner.find(params[:id])
     @book = @owner.books.build(params[:book])
     ....
   end
end
```

For details, closely look at [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) Article-Comment association example.

Comment: this is what I got: `Couldn't find Owner with 'id'=` when I put in this `@owner=Owner.find(params[:id])` in the create method of the Book controller.

Comment: do I really have to nest books within owners? I thought it was possible to do without that? I can see why you might think that based on the method I used in book's create ... but that was not my intent. Am I wrong in thinking that it is possible associate books and owners without have to nest it?

Comment: the method I put in book's controller method came from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354724/how-to-create-an-association-between-two-rails-models